# MS Access - Changing Query Criteria based on checkbox

Tags: ms-access, checkbox, filter

I've got a Query running which works fine now.  It lists all transaction done.  I want to add a checkbox to the Form that uses the Query to filter out any transaction with a Cancelled Date listed on it.  I've tried adding a Criteria to the CancelDate column on the query like this:

```
=IIf( Forms![Show DPA List]![chkShowCanc] =true,"*","IsNull")
```

And I keep getting a 'This Expression is typed incorrectly' error....

Is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: Even if the expression did not error, will still get a 'data type mismatch' error because the expression returns a text parameter to a date/time type field. I am assuming CancelDate is a date/time type.

Comment: I NEVER use dynamic parameterized query. Prefer VBA to build filter criteria and apply to form Filter property.

Comment: Please post the full SQL version of query so we can see how this expression is used.

Comment: Here is the SQL:

SELECT HillTop2nds.loanId, HillTop2nds.BondSeries, HillTop2nds.BondSeriesProgram, HillTop2nds.CancelDate, HillTop2nds.BondSeriesDesc,  HillTop2nds.ClosingDate
FROM HillTop2nds
WHERE (((HillTop2nds.CancelDate)=IIf([Forms]![Show DPA List]![chkShowCanc]=True,"*","IsNull")) AND ((HillTop2nds.BondSeriesDesc)=[Forms]![2ndLookup]![cmboSelectedDPA]));

Comment: Yes, once I learn VBA I might be of the same mind on approaching it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following does not error but it also won't return all records, wildcard returns only those with data in the field:

`LIKE IIf([Forms]![Show DPA List]![chkShowCanc], "*", Is Null)`

If you want to choose between all records or only those with null, calculate a field in query:

`F1: IIf([CancelDate] Is Null, "NoDate", "HasDate")`

Apply filter criteria to that field:

`LIKE IIf([Forms]![Show DPA List]![chkShowCanc], "NoDate", "*")`